# Problema al actualizar imagenes blob

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp

Estoy intentando actualizar una o dos imágenes de una tabla con un Servlet, los datos vienen de un formulario jsp, obtengo un error de vez en cuando y de vez en cuando los archivos se suben sin error, la pagina tarda en cargar y cuando lo hace me da este error java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: No se ha podido obtener un bloqueo en el tiempo solicitado

[image: Formulario]

Codigo del formulario JSP:

```jsp
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Modificar Museo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/formulario.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontello.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            Connection connection=null;
            Statement statement=null;
            Statement statement2=null;
            Statement statement3=null;
            ResultSet resultSet=null;
            ResultSet resultSet2=null;
            ResultSet resultSet3=null;
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PlanMuseumBDD");
            statement=connection.createStatement();
            statement2=connection.createStatement();
            statement3=connection.createStatement();
            int id_museo=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idmuseo"));
            int id_areatest=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idarea"));
            resultSet3=statement3.executeQuery("Select * from area where id_area="+id_areatest);
            resultSet=statement.executeQuery("Select * from museo where id_museo="+id_museo);
            resultSet2=statement2.executeQuery("Select * from area where id_area!="+id_areatest);
            while(resultSet.next()){
        %>
       <header>
            <div class="contenedor">
                <img src="img/PMLogo.png">
                <a href="index.jsp"><h1>PlanMuseum</h1></a>
                <input type='checkbox' id="menu-bar">
                <label class="icon-menu"for="menu-bar"></label>
                <nav class="menu">
                    <a href="index.jsp">Inicio</a>
                    <a href="Area.jsp">Area</a>
                    <a href="Museo.jsp">Museo</a>
                    <a href="Seccion.jsp">Seccion</a>
                    <a href="Beacon.jsp">Beacon</a>
                    <a href="Turno.jsp">Turno</a>
                    <a href="Plano.jsp">Planos</a>
                    <a href="Imagen.jsp">Imagen</a>
                    <a href="Usuario.jsp">Usuario</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="formulario">
            <h2>Ingrese los datos a modificar</h2>
            
            <form action="EditarMuseoServlet" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div>
                <label for="ID">ID :</label>
                <input id="ID" type="text" readonly="" name="txtIdMuseo" required value="<%= resultSet.getInt("id_museo")%>"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                <input id="nombre" type="text" name="txtNombreMuseo" required value="<%= resultSet.getString("nombre_museo")%>"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                <label for="area">Area :</label>
                <select id="area" name="IdArea">
                <% while (resultSet3.next()){    
                     int idArea = resultSet3.getInt("id_area");   
                     String nombreArea = resultSet3.getString("nombre_area");   
                %>
                    
                    <option value=<%= idArea%>><%= nombreArea%></option>
                <%}%>
                <% while (resultSet2.next()){    
                     int idArea = resultSet2.getInt("id_area");   
                     String nombreArea = resultSet2.getString("nombre_area");   
                %>
                    
                    <option value=<%= idArea%>><%= nombreArea%></option>
                <%}%>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                <label for="calle">Calle :</label>
                <input id="calle" type="text" name="txtCalle" required value="<%= resultSet.getString("calle")%>"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                <label for="altura">Altura :</label>
                <input id="altura" type="text" name="txtAltura" required value="<%= resultSet.getString("altura")%>"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                <label for="descripcion">Descripción :</label>
                <input id="descripcion" type="text" name="txtDescripcion" required value="<%= resultSet.getString("descripcion")%>"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                <label for="icono">Icono :</label>
                <input id="icono" type="file" name="perfil" >
                </div>
                <div>
                <label for="banner">Banner :</label>
                <input id="banner" type="file" name="banner" >
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
                <button onclick="location.href='Museo.jsp'" type="button">Volver</button>
            </form>
        <%}%>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código del Servlet para Modificar:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 80886080)//1.5mb
public class EditarMuseoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    Connection connection=null;
    Statement statement=null;
    ResultSet resultSet=null;
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException{
        super.init(config);
        try{
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PlanMuseumBDD");
            statement=connection.createStatement();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("No se pudo cargar el controlador: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Hubo un error en el SQL: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    PrintWriter out;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();
        int idMuseo=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtIdMuseo"));
        int idArea=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("IdArea"));
        String nombre_museo=request.getParameter("txtNombreMuseo");
        String calle=request.getParameter("txtCalle");
        String altura=request.getParameter("txtAltura");
        String desc=request.getParameter("txtDescripcion");
        Part perfil = request.getPart("perfil");
        Part banner = request.getPart("banner");
        if (perfil != null && banner!=null) {
            try {
                
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("update museo set nombre_museo=?,id_area=?,calle=?,altura=?,descripcion=?,perfil=?,bannerimg=? where id_museo="+idMuseo);
                InputStream fotoperfil = perfil.getInputStream();
                InputStream fotobanner = banner.getInputStream();
                ps.setString(1, nombre_museo);
                ps.setInt(2, idArea);
                ps.setString(3, calle);
                ps.setString(4, altura);
                ps.setString(5, desc);
                ps.setBlob(6, fotoperfil);
                ps.setBlob(7, fotobanner);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                response.sendRedirect("Museo.jsp");

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

No sé por qué a veces sube las imagenes correctamente y a veces no, aun dejando campos nulos debería funcionar pero esto no sucedce